# NullPointerException with Java Security Manager in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Jersey REST application, running on a Tomcat server. When enabling the Java Security Manager in Tomcat, I needed to grant several permissions related to hk2.

```
grant {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.injection.manager.strategy", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.jvnet.hk2.properties.debug.service.locator.lifecycle", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.jvnet.hk2.properties.bind.tracing.pattern", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.jvnet.hk2.properties.bind.tracing.stacks", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.jvnet.hk2.properties.useSoftReference", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.jvnet.hk2.logger.debugToStdout", "read";
    permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.webresources";
};
```

But I still get the following NullPointerException:

```
CRITICAL: Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/app] threw load() exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.addClasses(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:279)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

(I am using Jersey 2.30.1, which includes hk2 2.6.1)

Am I missing any permissions that should be granted?